# Lambda with variadic template

Tags: c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

Faced with the problem, which heard only within the gcc compiler. I have been programming in Visual Studio 2013 (update 3).

I need to create some objects in the some right thread.
Also, there is a need to be able to pass a function of their creation.

This code

```
class Object1;
class Object2;

class MyClass
{
    public:

        std::function<Object1*( const std::vector<int>& )> creatorForObject1() const;
        std::function<Object2*( int, double )> creatorForObject2() const;

    private:

        // exec 'handler' in other thread when there is a possibility
        void execInRightThread( std::function<void()> handler ) const;

        // need be called in right thread
        Object1& craeteObject1( const std::vector<int>& param );
        Object2& craeteObject2( int param1, double param2 );

        template<class TObject, class ...TParams>
        std::function<TObject*( TParams... )> creatorForObject( TObject&( MyClass::*creator )( TParams... ) ) const;
};


template<class TObject, class ...TParams>
std::function<TObject*( TParams... )> MyClass::creatorForObject( TObject&( MyClass::*creator )( TParams... ) ) const
{
    return [ this, &creator ]( TParams... params )
    {
        TObject* result = nullptr;
        MyClass& me = *const_cast<MyClass*>( this );
        me.execInRightThread( [ &me, &result, &creator, &params... ]()
        {
            result = &( me.*creator )( params... );
        } );
        while( result == nullptr );  // ugliness
        return result;
    };
}

std::function<Object1*( const std::vector<int>& )> MyClass::creatorForObject1() const
{
    return creatorForObject( &MyClass::craeteObject1 );
}

std::function<Object2*( int, double )> MyClass::creatorForObject2() const
{
    return creatorForObject( &MyClass::craeteObject2 );
}
```

report an errors

```
error C3521: 'params' is not a parameter pack
error C3546: '...' : there are no parameter packs available to expand
error C2065: 'params' : undeclared identifier
```

at the line

```
me.execInRightThread( [ &me, &result, &creator, &params... ]()
```

Please, help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with GCC 4.9.2.  What compiler version are you using?  Maybe you should upgrade.

Comment: Can't reproduce this under 4.9 upwards.

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Comment: I meant that I had read about similar problems with no new versions of gcc compilers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
template<class TObject, class ...TParams>
std::function<TObject*( TParams... )> MyClass::creatorForObject( TObject&( MyClass::*creator )( TParams... ) ) const
{
    return [ this, &creator ]( TParams... params )
    {
        TObject* result = nullptr;
        MyClass& me = *const_cast<MyClass*>( this );
        me.execInRightThread( [ & ]()
        {
            result = &( me.*creator )( params... );
        } );
        while( result == nullptr );  // ugliness
        return result;
    };
}
```

Maybe you should capture by value though...

Comment: Unfortunately, it has the same effect.

Comment: Also, I made a mistake.
There are instead
`me.execInRightThread( [ &me, &result, &creator, &params... ]()`
need
`me.execInRightThread( [ &me, &result, creator, &params... ]()`

Answer (score 0):

This works if the inner lambda make a separate function, but I do not understand why does not work above written.

```
class MyClass
{
   ...

    private:

        template<class TObject, class ...TParams>
        std::function<TObject*( TParams... )> creatorForObject( TObject&( MyClass::*creator )( TParams... ) ) const;

        template<class TObject, class ...TParams>
        TObject* temporaryCreator( TObject&( MyClass::*creator )( TParams... ), TParams... params );
};


template<class TObject, class ...TParams>
std::function<TObject*( TParams... )> MyClass::temporaryCreator( TObject&( MyClass::*creator )( TParams... ), TParams... params )
{
    TObject* result = nullptr;
    execInRightThread( [ this, &result, creator, &params... ]()
    {
        result = &( me.*creator )( params... );
    } );
    while( result == nullptr );  // ugliness
    return result;
}

template<class TObject, class ...TParams>
std::function<TObject*( TParams... )> MyClass::creatorForObject( TObject&( MyClass::*creator )( TParams... ) ) const
{
    MyClass& me = *const_cast<MyClass*>( this );
    return [ &me, creator ]( TParams... params )
    {
        return temporaryFunction<TObject, TParams...>( creator, params... );
    };
}
```